# point domain from cloudflare to hosting company

Tags: dns

Hello my current registrar for my domain fashbol is godaddy, but however i have my hosting with Hostnownow - A hosting company, which i switched too, when i was still using Godaddy as host i simply pointed my domain to Cloudflare and it worked, but when i changed however to my current host which is Hostnownow I pointed my domain to cloudflare as usual but no luck my website was not online, I then googled a solution and found out that i have to point my website domain to cloudflare and then on cloudflare DNS i should point my nameserver to my current hosting company which i did but no luck but however if i point it directly to my hosting company from godaddy the nameservers the website comes online if do not include cloudflare. My question is how do i point my website from cloudflare to my hosting company from cloudflare DNS settings , my website is already pointed from godaddy as registrar to cloudflare NOTE:cloudflare is not installed on my cpanel and my registrar is not a partner

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This site is intended as a programming Q&A. For questions like this about how to configure basic Internet services, you might want to head over to http://ServerFault.com. Or better yet, contact your vendor, who will actually provide one-on-one support for exactly this kind of question. I'm voting to close this question, as it's off-topic for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok basically you have three services (we all do)

Registrar:
They bill you for your domain

DNS:
Cloudflare in your case

Hosting:
Where your files are.

At your **registrar** you set up the name-servers for your domain,
in your case, check with cloudflare what they are.

In your **DNS (cloudflare)**, point the domain to your hosting,
check with the hosting company what type of DNS-settings ar required.